# NO matches found on a lookup field

Tags: custom-button, custom

I've a weird issue where am creating a parent opportunity record and from the same record I've a custom button where am creating a child record by populating some of the values but the issue here is on the child record there is a field called parent oppty where it is populating the value but throwing an error 'no matches found' even though value is populated. when I searched in google I found that it might due to special characters. Please help how to solve this issue. Below is the code

```
/006/e?recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Opportunity
&save_new_url=%2F006%2Fe%3F
&retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}
&CF00NU00000053wwx={!Opportunity.Name}
&opp3=Child Opp - {!Opportunity.Name}
&opp4_lkid={!Account.Id}
&opp7=0
&opp11={!Opportunity.StageName}
&opp9={!Opportunity.CloseDate}
&RecordType={!Opportunity.RecordTypeId}
```

Comment: Can you share the code

Comment: /006/e?recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Opportunity&save_new_url=%2F006%2Fe%3F&retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}& 
CF00NU00000053wwx={!Opportunity.Name} & 
opp3=Child Opp - {!Opportunity.Name}& 
opp4_lkid={!Account.Id}& 
opp7=0& 

opp11={!Opportunity.StageName}&opp9={!Opportunity.CloseDate} 
&RecordType={!Opportunity.RecordTypeId}

Comment: @ArifHussain Please edit your question to include this information, rather than making comments.

Comment: You should have pass opportunity Id on parent opportunity lookup but you are passing opportunity name. Can you try like account id how you are passing on Account.

Comment: @PremAnandh if you see the code I already passed the Id.

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern of how you populate a lookup field via a URL hack looks like this:

```
/<keyprefix>/e?CF<lookup_field_id>_lkid={!Opportunity.Id} 
&CF<lookup_field_id>={!Opportunity.Name}
```

Note that you obtain the field Id of the Lookup Field and then add *two* entries to your URL hack: one with CF + the lookup field id set to the Name of the linked record, and one with CF + the lookup field id + `_lkid` set to the Id of the target record. You're not populating the Id of the target record here.